# Android build a custom back stack for fragments

Tags: java, android

I would like to build a custom history stack for my fragments. I have already implemented the logic to show and hide each of them (whatever their total count). Now I would like to be able to press back and get to the previous, according to the requirements (scenario below).

Let's say that we have 4 views(fragments) : A,B,C and D. Every time you see x -> y it means that a button was pressed from x to go to y. This is what I want:

- scenario 1:(Stack) A -> B -> C -> D. If I press back from D I jump back on C and so on to A (like the back feature in a browser) and the stack removes the upper one. So from D to C, the resulting stack is now A -> B -> C
- scenario 2:(Stack) A -> C ->B -> D. If I press a button to go to C from D, I want the new state of the stack to be A -> C as D and B are cleared from the stack. Like a collapse. When I will press back from C now it will send me back                to A, and the stack will have only A.

So far, I have created a Stack `viewManager = new Stack<>();` (in the parent's activity) that stores integers (each integer represents one of my views A,B,C and D). My idea was that every time that I add a view and add its integer to the stack.

This is my addViewToStack method:

```
     public final void addViewToStack(Integer theView){
        //if empty
        if(viewManager == null)
            viewManager = new Stack<>();

        //if it has no view add the current view
        if(viewManager.size() == 0) {
            viewManager.push(Integer.valueOf(theView));
            return;
        }

        //if the view is already at the top, do nothing
        if(viewManager.peek() == Integer.valueOf(theView))
            return;
        else {
            int viewPosition = viewManager.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(theView));
            if(viewPosition == -1) { //if not found in the stack
                viewManager.push(Integer.valueOf(theView));
            }
            else{ //if already in the stack we remove all the elements above
                while (viewManager.size() > 0) {
                    if (viewPosition < viewManager.size() -1 )
                        viewManager.pop();
                    else //we reached the element
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, this is the pressBack method:

```
    public final void pressBack(){
        if(viewManager == null || viewManager.isEmpty())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The view manager is null or empty. You must have at least two fragments before calling pressBack()");

        viewManager.pop();
        changeView(viewManager.peek());
    }
```

And the changeView method:

```
public void changeView(int destination){
    switch (destination) {

        case  VIEW_A_ID:
            //launch the view
            break;

        case  VIEW_B_ID:
            //launch the view
            break;

        case  VIEW_C_ID:
            //launch the view
            break;

        case VIEW_D_ID:
            //launch the view
            break;

        default:
            //do nothing
            break;
    }
    addViewToStack(destination);
}
```

Now the problem is that sometimes I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException thrown at me. Can you guys please help me to understand what is wrong (I have spent already two days on this)?

Comment: I haven't read your question, but if possible in any way, don't create a custom fragment stack!

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @SarthakMittal Why shouldn't I do so? I want a certain behavior that is not the default one.

Comment: @Krish I have been debugging it. Now I'll just try to put a break point on each and every line.

Comment: @MaximeClaude I read your scenario's and they can be easily implemented with default fragment backstack.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug. There was a place in the code that set the `viewmanager = null` . It works as intended.